# proofs of floor topology, dense subsets and countable bases.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

[image]

I am absolutely clueless here, I know that $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable dense subset, if below propositions hold true:

The rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ are a countable set, and when you give $\mathbb{R}$ the standard (order) topology, then the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

So, based on these definitions, if I declare $[0,1)$ and $[1,2)$ which follows the notaions of floor topology, then how should I prove or show that they have a countable basis and dense subset in $T_{ll}$?

Need help on this.

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is still dense. It intersects every base element of the standard base.

Comment: How to solve problems 3.68 and 69? I know the definitions of standard order topology and floor topology but I really don't know how to make use of it.

Comment: Have you looked at the duplicate? I gave you the argument for 3.68 already in the other comment: a set is dense iff it intersects every non-empty base element. $(a,b) \subseteq [a,b)$ and you already know $\Bbb Q$ is dense in the standard topology!